# Sidebar Enhancement plugin installed but not working

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04

system configuration: *Sublime text3 build 3065 + Ubuntu 14.04*

I want to add preview in Browser and found that [**Siderbar Enhancement (SBE)**](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) is best plugin to do that.  Below are the steps i have done

1. Folder added and project and work space created in ST3
2. Install [SBE], following the instructions. First removed previous instance of SBE and then install via via Package Control
3. Restart the ST3.

But still no menu in folder context menu?

Is that any issue with plugin/system or am I missing something? Please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, I got the answer:

*SideBarEnhancements* was added in ignored packages (Don't know Why and How)

So just remove *SideBarEnhancements* from **Preferences.sublime-settings**

```
"ignored_packages":
    [
        "JSLint",
        "CSS3",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "Vintage",
        "SublimeLinter-php",
        "SideBarEnhancements", << remove this 
        "JavaScript"
    ],
```

Now everything is fine

Comment: Here too... dunno why!

Comment: I didn't see the menu but read the documentation: `First please note this package only adds a context menu to the "Folders" section and not to the "Open Files" section.`. So I used `File/Open Folder...` and there it is.

Answer (score 15):

Exactly as posted above. The context menu is added to the folders section. So most probably you are trying to see it when you click on open files.

Here is what you do:

1. Close side-bar
2. File > Open Folder > (Open any folder)
3. View > Show Side Bar

This worked for me.

Comment: I don't see an open folder option in File mentu