# Sublime Text 3, Sidebar enhancements not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I have installed the [sidebar enhancements package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) using the package installer in ST3 on Windows 10.

The installation does not seem to have worked correctly.

Right clicking the sidebar only shows a few options.

I've tried reinstalling it but the problem persisted.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are on Windows so the universal advice always applies.

"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8

Comment: @jwpfox lol i love that show

Comment: Open the containing folder of the files you wish to see. [Answer from this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167587/sidebar-enhancement-plugin-installed-but-not-working)